# Selenium - downloading files

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, download

I am trying to run a script to visit the Nasdaq website to download the stock information for a list of companies in the last 18 months. After running the following script I only managed to open the Firefox page with the company info and the download button, but it would not download it for me right away.

Why?

def pull_nasdaq_data(tickers, save_path, rm_path):

```
# To prevent download dialog box in selenium
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', r'C:\Users\Filippo Sebastio\Desktop\Stock')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, application/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/download, application/octet-stream, binary/octet-stream, application/binary, application/x-unknown")

# Setup Webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Filippo Sebastio\Desktop\geckodriver.exe')


popup = True  # Will there be a popup?

for ticker in tickers:
    # Get the stocks website
    site = 'http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/' + ticker + '/historical'
    driver.get(site)
    # Choose 10 year data from a drop down
    data_range = driver.find_element_by_name('ddlTimeFrame')
    for option in data_range.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if option.text == '18 Months':
            option.click()
            break
    time.sleep(10)

    # Click to Download Data
    driver.find_element_by_id('lnkDownLoad').click()

    # Open the file from the downloads folder
    time.sleep(25)  # Wait for file to download
    data = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/HistoricalQuotes.csv')

    # Rename and save the file in the desired location
    file_loc = save_path + ticker + '.csv'
    data.to_csv(file_loc, index=False)

    # Delete the downloaded file
    os.remove(removal_path)

    print("Downloaded:  ", ticker)

    # Wait for the next page to load
    time.sleep(20)  


tickers = ['tesla', 'mmm']  
save_path = my patht to where I want the docuemnts downloaded
rm_path = my Download path 

pull_nasdaq_data(tickers, save_path, rm_path)
```

Comment: From my experience, Selenium does not directly download files into your standard user downloads folder (my guess is you are using windows). The way I get around this is to manipulate the file directly. For example, when accessing websites to download a CSV, I read the CSV directly into Pandas. For accessing a .TXT file, I read it directly by setting the file path to the remote location.

Comment: ok thanks! Can you point me to some documentation or script example? that's be awesome!

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: Basically Selenium opens the right firefox page with the company info, the time frame I want to download the data for, but does not download the data. Also, it opens only the webpage for my first company in my list, not the second.